# Getting 301 with Flutter OAuth

Tags: flutter, authentication, dart

It's sad to see no concrete examples are available when it comes to using OAuth2 package of Flutter.

I'm a beginner, the example mentioned [here](https://pub.dev/packages/oauth2#authorization-code-grant) is tough for me to crack(I learn mostly through videos), but my job requires me to implement OAuth by today itself. So I'm trying my shot here.

This is what I've:

```
Login API

curl --location --request POST 'https://domain/api/rest/oauth/token' \

--header 'Authorization: Basic XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX' \

--header 'Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' \

--data-urlencode 'grant_type=password' \

--data-urlencode 'username=<username_here>' \

--data-urlencode 'password=<md5_of_password_here'
```

I've been given a sample username and password as well..

This is what I've implemented so far..

```
void checkAuthentication() async {
    String username = 'username';
    String password = 'password';

    String basicAuth =
        'Basic ' + base64Encode(utf8.encode('$username:$password'));
    print(basicAuth);

    var body = jsonEncode(
      <String, dynamic>{
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'username': 'username',
        'password': 'password',
      },
    );

    Response r = await http.post(
      Uri.https('domain', 'api/rest/oauth/token'),
      headers: <String, String>{
        'authorization': basicAuth,
        'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
        'accept': 'application/json',
      },
      body: body,
    );
    print(r.statusCode);
    print(r.headers);
    print(r.body);
  }
```

I'm getting 301 as result..

What can I do to get 200. Please guide me.

Comment: I'm also not sure if I'm proceeding in the right direction. Your guidance will save my day.

Comment: Are you using the correct url? https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/301

Comment: @ManishPaul Did u solved it??